# How to run multiple containers within the same pod in kubernetes clusture?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-compose

I have 2 docker containers. one containing tomcat server and the other containing MySQL database. I want to run those containers on a single pod since tomcat has to access the MySQL database.

What I have tried:

pod.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: tomcat-mysql-pod
  labels:
  app: tomcat-mysql-pod
spec:
containers:
- name: kubernetestomcatcontainer
  image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
  ports:
- containerPort: 8080
containers:
- name: kubernetesmysqlcontainer
  image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
  ports:
- containerPort: 3306
```

I ran this pod using

```
kubectl apply -f pod.yaml
```

then I exposed the pod using

```
kubectl expose pod tomcat-mysql-pod --type=NodePort --port=8080
```

Currently, I can only access the tomcat homepage using `https://serveripaddress:nodeport` but not my spring boot app using `https://serveripaddress:nodeport/data-core-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`???

**NOTE**: The app works and ran perfectly when running the containers using docker-compose.yaml and then the docker-compose up command. But when I run this on kubernetes I get Catalina lifecycle exception in tomcat's manager app while starting my war file.

Comment: You’d almost always run these two things separately: a Deployment for Tomcat, and a StatefulSet with an attached PersistentVolumeClaim for MySQL, plus a Service in front of each.

Comment: can u give me an example?? I mean how should the yaml file look like if I run them seperately??

Comment: actually i also tried converting the docker-compose.yaml to kubeternete using kompose convert but still my war file failed to start

Answer (score 0):

That `containers:` line in your YAML snippet is the **name** of a collection and items in it should be enumerated using dashes indented at the same column.

You should try something like:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: tomcat-mysql-pod
  labels:
  app: tomcat-mysql-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: kubernetestomcatcontainer
    image: suji165475/vignesh:tomcatserver
    ports:
      containerPort: 8080
  - name: kubernetesmysqlcontainer
    image: suji165475/vignesh:latest
    ports:
      containerPort: 3306
```

Comment: i says error: error validating "pod.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(Pod.metadata): unknown field "app" in io.k8s.apimachinery.pkg.apis.meta.v1.ObjectMeta, ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[0].ports): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.ports: got "map", expected "array", ValidationError(Pod.spec.containers[1].ports): invalid type for io.k8s.api.core.v1.Container.ports: got "map", expected "array"]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to run both ui and database services in the same pod. It would enable hard coupling between ui and db.

Better to run ui and db in a separate pods. Ui can communicate mysql database using service dns. Consider running mysql In  stateful set to maintain the application state

Comment: I though containers in same pod can communicate using shared volume??

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/communicate-containers-same-pod-shared-volume/

Comment: you can run more than one container in a pod. but is not a good practice.

Comment: If  i create a deployment for tomcat and statefulset for mysql with persistent volume...would that be a good practice??

Comment: I tried that method but my war file is not starting in tomcat manager app!!

Comment: is there any other way ?? I mean would like to run my docker-compose.yaml on  kubernetes clusture